# Install xubuntu on top of existing system

Tags: boot, partitioning, xubuntu, lvm

I have ubuntu 16.04 which I tried to do `do-dist-update` to bionic, which ended up in a total mess, unbootable (keep loading).

I have liveusb with xubuntu 20.04. Currently I jave /dev/sda1 for boot (ext2) and  LVM on the rest (with one / partition /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root). I want to install xubuntu in a way, that it will replace current system, but won't erase /home directory, which is on that partition. Is it doable?

Comment: You can re-install using "*Something else*" then select your existing partitions, and as long as you don't format partition(s), it'll note your installed packages, erase system directories, install new system, attempt to add back your additional packages (noted earlier) IF available on new release in Ubuntu repositories, then ask to reboot. It doesn't touch user directories (unless you selected format). I've used it with LVM, but have more experience with non-LVM partitions, and it allows you to skip releases (ie. go from 16.04 to 20.04; re-install same release, or go to earlier release)

Comment: Would back up any important data you want to keep first.  If /home is separate partition, it is slightly safer for none back up data.

Comment: yeah, I'll buy 64GB SD card and copy /home and /etc first. The partition selection for installation was bit weird there, I'll try to paste a screenshot in the evening, but I was rather confused. Thanks for your replies anyway!

Comment: You will have a cleaner system doing a fresh install, then placing only your user files, and perhaps very limited config data (e.g. thunderbird) back.